# Is this factory method causing a race condition?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

Given this c++ snippet, will the use of `Factory::make_stooge()` in multiple threads cause a race condition?
(original snippet from https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype/cpp/1)

```
/*Base class*/
class Stooge {
public:
   virtual Stooge* clone() = 0;
   virtual void slap_stick() = 0;
};

/*Factory class*/
class Factory {
public:
   static Stooge* make_stooge( int choice );
private:
   static Stooge* s_prototypes[4];
};

/*Derived class*/
class Larry : public Stooge {
public:
   Stooge*   clone() { return new Larry; }
   void slap_stick() {
      cout << "Larry: poke eyes\n"; }
};

/*Derived class*/
class Moe : public Stooge {
public:
   Stooge*   clone() { return new Moe; }
   void slap_stick() {
      cout << "Moe: slap head\n"; }
};

/*Derived class*/
class Curly : public Stooge {
public:
   Stooge*   clone() { return new Curly; }
   void slap_stick() {
      cout << "Curly: suffer abuse\n"; }
};

/*First thread function*/
void *make100Larrys(void *arg) {
  Stooge** Larrys = (Stooge*)arg;
  for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
  {
     Larrys[i] = Factory::make_stooge(1);
  }
  pthread_exit();
}

/*Second thread function*/
void *make100Moes(void *arg) {
  Stooge** Moes = (Stooge*)arg;
  for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
  {
     Moes[i] = Factory::make_stooge(2);
  }
  pthread_exit();
}



int main() {
   vector<Stooge*> roles;
   int choice;

   while (true) {
      cout << "Larry(1) Moe(2) Curly(3) Go(0): ";
      cin >> choice;
      if (choice == 0)
         break;
      roles.push_back(
         Factory::make_stooge( choice ) );
   }

   for (int i=0; i < roles.size(); ++i)
      roles[i]->slap_stick();
   for (int i=0; i < roles.size(); ++i)
      delete roles[i];

   //Second Edit
   pthread_t LarryThread;
   Stooge* Larrys[100];

   pthread_t MoeThread;
   Stooge* Moes[100];

   pthread_create(&LarryThread, NULL, make100Larrys, Larrys);
   pthread_create(&MoeThread, NULL, make100Moes, Moes);

   void** status;
   pthread_join(LarryThread, status);
   pthread_join(MoeThread, status);

}


/*Static variable initialization*/ 
Stooge* Factory::s_prototypes[] = {
   0, new Larry, new Moe, new Curly
};

/*Factory method*/
Stooge* Factory::make_stooge( int choice ) {
   return s_prototypes[choice]->clone();
}
```

My thought is that if `s_prototypes` is instantiated while only one thread exists, `Factory::make_stooge()` is technically re-entrant.

EDIT: Perhaps a better phrasing of my question would be: Could I start some number of threads in `main()` that each  called `Factory::make_stooge()`?

Comment: Note that "re-entrant" and "thread-safe" are two different things.

Comment: `vector roles;` shouldn't compile.

Comment: If you have #include <vector> , it should compile .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provided code (notwithstanding several issues with it, typos and more serious ones) is thread-safe - in a sense that it does not have a thread race in it. The question 'is the function thread-safe' can rarely be answered for a specific function.

The reason for the code to not have a thread race is straightforward - there is a single thread of execution in the whole program. With modified question, yes, you can add more threads which would call `Factory::make_stooge` simultaneously, there will be no thread race still **with the current code**.

Comment: You are correct. But if I were to start multiple threads in `main()`, could I call `Factory::make_stooge()` to make instances of concrete `Stooge` objects  in each?

Comment: The question was is this function thread safe.  The threadsafety of a function or object or library does not depend on the number of threads in the process.

Comment: @UKMonkey, like I said in my comment, tread-safe is vague. The correct question is 'does this code has a thread race'. The answer is no.

Comment: @SergeyA that's not the correct question.  It's "can I add more threads to this safely"

Comment: @UKMonkey you a free to disagree with me. And yes, you can add more threads. Safely. Millions of them.

Comment: @UKMonkey seen and answered.

Comment: My apologies, if the question/example was too vague; Would the current edit of the code snippet cause a thread race?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add more threads to create Larry/Moe/Curly. But this line of code:
    Stooge* Factory::s_prototypes[] = {
    0, new Larry, new Moe, new Curly
    };
creates instance of Larry, Moe and Curly even before you take input from user and never get into action. But the instances that were created by user input are stored in roles. Instead, I wouldn't have s_prototypes at all and  modify make_stooge :

```
Stooge *Stooge::make_stooge(int choice)
{
    if (choice == 1)
      return new Larry;
    else if (choice == 2)
      return new Moe;
    else
      return new Curly;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be; but I wouldn't bet on it.

A single thread of execution in the program (programs aren't ever thread safe or not) does not make an object thread safe; since you might decide to add a thread later.

Your s_prototypes is only read; in the function you're asking about, but it isn't const.  As such there might be something changing it under the hood.  On top of that something could also be changing the instances of those prototypes since they're not const either.

Finally, clone isn't const; which suggests that it could be changing something in the object.  If that's the case, then it's much less likely to be thread safe; (and with no visibility on the function it can't be confirmed either way).

Comment: A function taken in isolation can rarely be attributed as thread-safe or not. Even in the simplest case with `std::map::find`, is `find` thread-safe? If a function which locks a mutex in the beginning and unlocks it in the end is thread -safe? No idea. As a matter of fact, *thread-safe* is a misnomer, and is too vague. The better question is 'does this code have a race'. And this question can only be answered looking at the code in whole, in execution paths, and not by looking at the single function.

Comment: @SergeyA Correct - which is why I say "it might be" and then explain the bits that suggest it wouldn't be; rather than what is clearly not the right answer; "yes".